# Can standart GWT app run different because of different Internet Browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, gwt, plugins, gwt-designer

Today I tested my test app in gwt dev mode in different Internet Browsers.

- A) IE7
- B) FF4

for some reason app runs fine in IE7 only but in FF4.0 it is loosing many-layers support. For example it doesn't support this kind of structure algorythm

- SplitLayoutPanel "A" (left: tree; right: simple panel "B" with Button "C")
- Event: Button "C" clicked - simple panel "B" setWidget SplitLayoutPanel "D"

So... it is no SplitLayoutPanel "D" is shown :( Instead of SplitLayoutPanel "D" it is a blank simple panel "B" :( But the thing is... All the same works fine in IE7 and eclipse gwt designer...

So my question is can GWT app run wrong depending of Internet Browser and its GWT dev plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: yes. Ultimately you are running HTML/Javascript code on different browsers and will as such be subjected to those platform's variations. Google try hard to shelter you from many problems, but I've come across differences.

Comment: but why? I always thought that FF is more close to JS, is it? but IE seems to be more close to GWT 2.3 then?